# Присваивание значения переменной пользователем (java)

Tags: java

Можно ли в Java присвоить значение ранее не инициализированной переменной при запуске программы? Переменной любого типа. Не через string[] args.

Comment: можно................

Comment: А как? если не секрет.

Comment: точно так же, как если бы сразу инициализировали......переменная = значение

Comment: т.е. при таком коде:
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int var;
        System.out.println(var);
    }
и запуске:
java Program var=42
я получу в консоли:
42

Comment: а причём тут `java Program var=42` ?  Значение  присваимвается в коде программы. При этом откуда значение прилетит совершенно не важно....... условно говоря будет так `java Program 42`  и `int var; var= Integer.parseInt(args[0]); System.out.println(var); `

Comment: отмечаю еще раз, НЕ через string[] args, т.е. без последующего парсинга итд...
типа как в Си при вызове компилятора добавляется var=42 и программа работает с этим значением

Comment: Без понятия как там в СИ.Значение в любом случае долнжно как-то попасть в код....попадёт оно в любом случае только через args. (либо например через файл). Вы, по сути, хотите **физически** вписать строку кода в сам код из консоли..Это нельзя

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете распарсить входные аргументы и инициализировать необходимые переменные после этого

```
java Program --current-folder=C:/MAIN --next-folder=C:/MAIN/NEXT


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       String current_folder = args[0].substring(args[0].indexOf('=')+1, args[0].length()); 
       String next_folder = args[1].substring(args[1].indexOf('=')+1, args[1].length());
       System.out.println(current_folder);
       System.out.println(next_folder);
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
C:/MAIN
C:/MAIN/NEXT
```